# What is the admin command to spawn the heat suit?

Tags: starbound

Normally a player would defeat the giant robot to get the heat suit, but I can't quite pull that victory off. What is the admin command to spawn the heat suit tech?

*update*

My workaround was discovering that using the `/admin` command makes you invincible. So I used that to cheat through the boss fight, but I would still like to know how the spawning commands for tech works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat protection nanosuit is not "spawned" per se. Rather, it is a tech that must be enabled using a command so that it can be equipped from the AI interface.

```
/aiaction {"action":"enableTech", "techName":"heatprotectionTech"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely know how to use it, but I think it's something like /spawnitem heatSuit 1
that SHOULD spawn one heat suit, but I'm positive about that. If it doesn't work, try playing around with it. Here's a link to the list of commands, maybe that will help.
http://starbounder.org/Server_Commands